# How can i pass the base64 string as a input certificate for Openssl?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, openssl, sh

I have a certificate which i am getting in string . I just want that string to be directly pass as `-in` in the openssl command.

But i don't see any method in openssl , can you help.

my code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

        exec('openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in '+certificateString , (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(studout);
        }
        });
```

If i directly pass certificate file url it works, like this

> openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in certificate.pem

this work

but how can i pass the certificate string directly in openssl ?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do you have base64 or PEM? Those are not the same thing; although PEM *includes* base64, it is not *only* base64. If you have a file that works with `openssl x509 -in file` then it is PEM, **NOT** only base64. People seem to look at PEM, see more than 40 base64 characters, and their brains shut down and become unable to see the dashes-BEGIN line, the dashes-END line, and the line breaks, all of which are REQUIRED.

Second, `certificate.pem` is a filename or pathname, not a URL. A filename or pathname is not a URL, and a URL is not a filename or pathname, although *some* URL schemes (and particularly the only ones most people notice) include some elements in common with pathnames.

The certificate input to `openssl x509` must be either a (named) file, or standard input (commonly abbreviated stdin). If you don't want to supply it as a named file, `nodejs` can provide data to a child's stdin, but not with the higher-level `exec*` methods, only the more basic `spawn`:

```
const{ spawn } = require('child_process');
const pem = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`;
const p = spawn("/path/to/openssl", ["x509","-noout","-issuer"]);
// options.stdio defaults to ['pipe','pipe','pipe'] 
p.stdout.on('data',(data)=> {console.log(data.toString())} );
p.stderr.on('data',(data)=> {console.log("ERROR:"+data.toString())} );
p.on('close',()=> {} );
p.stdin.write(pem); p.stdin.end();
```

However, you don't need to run an external program to parse a certificate; there are lots of JS libraries to do it. For example, with the second one npmjs finds for me:

```
const { Certificate } = require('@fidm/x509');
const { ASN1 } = require('@fidm/asn1');
var iss = Certificate.fromPEM(pem).issuer.attributes;
var s = ""; for(var a of iss){ s += "/" + a.shortName + "=" + a.value; }
console.log(s);
```

If you actually did have base64 and not PEM, replace the third line with

```
const bin = Buffer.from(b64,'base64');
var iss = new Certificate(ASN1.fromDER(bin)).issuer.attributes;
```

Comment: Thanks man , but does `crypto` is not able to do this . https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: Not that I can see. Of course nodejs is opensource, so you could add this, using the openssl library that is already embedded and used for other things. Or put in a feature request; the `tls` module already supports openssl cert operations related to TLS connections, but that requires the matching privatekey for a local cert.